# Why does Android ViewGroup scale child images at its edges?

Tags: android, viewgroup

I use a ViewGroup as a container to place multiple instances of a smaller-sized icon image at arbitrary locations. When the icons are placed near the bottom or right edge of the container, they are automatically scaled to fit within the bounds of the ViewGroup. Why does this happen, and how do I prevent it? I set the clipChildren attribute on the ViewGroup to FALSE to see if that worked, but it doesn't.

The ViewGroup is added dynamically. m_iconContainer is the ViewGroup which parents the icons.

```
m_outerContainer = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById( R.id.outer );
m_iconContainer = new ScalingFrameLayout( getActivity() );
m_outerContainer.addView( m_iconContainer );
```

Icons are added in a straightforward manner:

```
PinImage p = new PinImage( getActivity() );
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) p.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin = pt.x - PIN_IMAGE_XOFFSET;
params.topMargin = pt.y - PIN_IMAGE_YOFFSET;
m_iconContainer.addView( p );

public class ScalingFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private float scale = 1;

    public ScalingFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        setClipChildren(false);
    }

    public void setScale(float factor) {
        scale = factor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public float getScale() {
        return scale;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.scale(scale, scale);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}


protected class PinImage extends ImageView {
    public PinImage( Context c ) {
    super( c );
    setLayoutParams( new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT ));
    setImageResource( R.drawable.droppin );
        this.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                 onCommentPinTouched( v );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/asset_group"android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@id/upper_details_layout" android:layout_above="@id/toolbar_layout"
      android:background="#000000">
   <shared.components.ZoomPanImage android:id="@+id/asset_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:contentDescription="@string/nil_content_desc" android:scaleType="matrix" />
  </FrameLayout>

Comment: What is shared.components.ZoomPanImage? And where is your ViewGroup?

Comment: Sorry, I tried putting the code sample in the wrong place. This bit is irrelevant.

Comment: I already tried. `ScalingFrameLayout` should be the parent in XML layout, in your parent, should add `Image View` with the image & set `scaleType` centerInside. You should see the scale view group you want.